# MVP and BaseActivity - Best practices

Tags: android, mvp

I'm on my way to build my first Android app using the MVP Pattern.
Everything seems quite clear unless **the way I should handle the usage of a BaseActivity**.

The purpose of the BaseActivity would be to have the navigationDrawer for instance, the options menu as well as some other methods that might be common to other activities.

**My questions are:**

- How do you handle a BaseActivity in an MVP structure?
- Would you create a contract as well?
- Would you put the common methods in an utils class instead of inside the BaseActivity and call it in the Presenter? Not sure that it is always possible

I'm looking forward to your best advices,

Here is my current structure:

[image: Current MVP Structure]

Comment: You can extend All activities with BaseActitities please look into this http://www.tinmegali.com/en/model-view-presenter-mvp-in-android-part-2/
Seet the first comment

Comment: I was on it, but "I really don’t know exactly what you mean by BaseActivity pattern" is your answer in the comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi Using MVP pattern you can handle many things,

1. You dont need any settings of toolbar.
2. You can set title and other things directly from base activity.
3. Set fonts using Calligraphy directly from base activity.
4. Declare Butter knife  in base activity
5. Setting layout
6. Handle any exception during api calls.
7. Define using abstract methods how to manage the lifecycle.

and many more things that we can hanlde in base activity.

MVP use for better optimization of code.

You will do all business logic in Presenter.

I have create one project base.

See for more [details](https://github.com/saveendhiman/SampleApp).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, your link is just awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should put all code there that you want to share between all activities. You can provide a presenter in a common way for there. You can call presenter's lifecycle methods if you like to make presenter aware of the activity lifecycle. Usually I would implement the sliding menu as a separate view that has its own presenter

Answer (score 0):

In MVP in android Activity/Fragment - it's your View
In onActivityCreated(...) you create your presenter;
Navigation between screens declare in View.

Actually you need not create Interface for your Presenter:
http://blog.karumi.com/interfaces-for-presenters-in-mvp-are-a-waste-of-time/

Best practices: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture